# How to initialize DB in Jest for a group of tests?

Tags: javascript, database, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Does Jest allow for "group" setup (for a group of tests that are in different files)?

I tried to do it like this,

```js
let sequelize = null

beforeAll(async () => {
  sequelize = await initDataBase(config)
})

afterAll(async () => {
  await sequelize.drop()
})

describe('DB testing', () => {
  it('Test #0', () => expect(true).toEqual(true))
  testGroupZero(sequelize)()
  describe('Test Group #1', testGroupOne(sequelize))
  describe('Test Group #2', testGroupTwo(sequelize))
  })
})
```

but `testGroupZero()()` and internal `describe()` handlers still run before `beforeAll()`.